# Facebook Like Box theme issue?

Tags: facebook, themes, facebook-likebox

Integrated the FB like box in our site . It working the problem is that i designed the  FB code(html) with theme dark but it showing the light . How can i fix this.
Please help me

Comment: how are you including the plugin? Are you definitely specifying the dark version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include the colorscheme="dark" attribute in the fb:like tag.